# What is the white powdery substance on my Dracaena's leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, dracaena

I bought a Dracaena about 3 months ago.  I water it 1-2 times a week and make sure the soil is moist, but not too damp.  About 3 weeks ago, it started developing a white powdery substance on the leaves.  Can you tell me what this is or what I can do to get rid of it?

Comment: a picture please!

Answer (score 5):

In lieu of a picture, here is a blind guess: it is one of powdery mildew, a scale bug of some sort, or mineral deposits.

It is probably a scale bug.